# Kubernetes Edit File In A Pod

Tags: kubernetes

I have used some bitnami charts in my kubernetes app. In my pod, there is a file whose path is /etc/settings/test.html. I want to override the file. When I search it, I figured out that I should mount my file by creating a configmap. But how can I use the created configmap with the **existed pod** . Many of the examples creates a new pod and uses the created config map. But I dont want to create a new pod, I wnat to use the existed pod.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If not all then almost all pod specs are immutable, meaning that you can't change them without destroying the old pod and creating a new one with desired parameters. There is *no way* to edit pod volume list without recreating it.

The reason behind this is that pods aren't meant to be immortal. Pods meant to be temporary units that can be spawned/destroyed according to scheduler needs. In general, you need a workload object that does pod management for you (a `Deployement`, `StatefulSet`, `Job`, or `DaemonSet`, depenging on deployment strategy and application nature).

There are two ways to edit a file in an existing pod: either by using `kubectl exec` and console commands to edit the file in place, or `kubectl cp` to copy an already edited file into the pod. I advise you against *both of these*, because this is not permanent. Better backup the necessary data, switch deployment type to `Deployment` with one replica, then go with mounting a `configMap` as you read on the Internet.

Answer (score 1):

To edit a file inside a pod you need to install vim inside the pod, run this:

```
apt-get update && apt-get install vim curl -y
```

after which you can continue with vim commands. You can also replace vim for nano if you like.